# How to set number of terminal rows on Arch Linux installer

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation

I'm attempting to install Arch onto a 2016 Macbook pro - however when the actual installer prompt starts, the screen buffer overflows below the bottom of the screen. As a result, the active prompt is being rendered somewhere below the visible screen, and I can't see what I'm typing nor what the response is (until I press enter a bunch of times to move the text up).

Is there any way to reduce the number of rows the installer terminal renders? I've tried using the vga command line setting in GRUB, but that so far has had no effect.

EDIT: I should mention I have also tried changing the font via setfont - while this does change the font size, the installer still runs off the bottom of the screen once it is reached.

Answer (score 0):

setfont temporarily change the font if passed a font name (in /usr/share/kbd/consolefonts/) such as

setfont -h8 /usr/share/kbd/consolefonts/*nameoffontandsize*.psfu.gz

example

> setfont -h8 /usr/share/kbd/consolefonts/drdos8x8.psfu.gz

[from the wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Linux_console#Preview_and_temporary_changes)

Comment: Ive tried that as well - it shrinks the font, but the rows still overrun the bottom of the screen (though it does allow more to be shown on screen before it does, however)